# Is there a way to attach to a remote process?

Tags: linux, networking, remote

I'm currently stuck with remote debugging issue of my application with `gdb`. I would like to have the ability to attach to a remote process and use `IDE`'s visual debugging (I use `Visual Studio Code`).

The problem is IDE can attach to a local process by its `pid` which is not really useful. So if I request local port forwarding I could use the local port to forward the connection which is again not really what I want.

Is it possible to do something like "pid-forwarding" i.e. I set some `pid` which is actually a remote process.

Comment: You're not telling what IDE are using (and as I'm not using any IDE, I probably wouldn't be able to help you). But you should look into gdbserver -- that's a small program that could run on an embedded/restrained system, and you could connect to it with the 'fat debugger' from a more powerful machine.

Comment: @UncleBilly I did. "I use Visual Studio Code". Unfortunately it is documented that it does not support remote debugging...

Comment: @UncleBilly _gdbserver_ sounds like it is what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [Uncle Billy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/325065/uncle-billy) says, a nice way to do this is to use GDB’s remote debugging capabilities. This works by running a “small” debugger on the host running the process you want to debug, and connecting to it using `gdb` from the host running your development environment. Since many IDEs (including VS Code) support debugging using `gdb`, you can get the comfort of your development environment targeted at processes running anywhere, including on other platforms.

On the host running the process you want to debug, you need to install `gdbserver` (often by copying a static binary), and run it; for example:

```
gdbserver --attach :9953 ${pid}
```

will list on port 9953 and attach to the given process id. You can specify a variety of ways to connect to the server (serial ports, IP addresses...), and either run a command to debug, or attach to a running process, or even run a “debugging server” with no specific process.

On the host with your development environment, you connect to the target within `gdb`:

```
$ gdb ...

(gdb) target remote <IP address>:9953
```

Everything else works as usual. `gdb` will transfer files it needs (libraries etc.) from the remote target, but to speed things up you can point it at a local copy of the files. It will use local sources.

This works as you’d expect when the two hosts are the same, but it can also be made to work with different hosts, *e.g.* to debug a Windows program from a Linux system, or more typically, a program running on a small embedded system from a bigger development platform.